# Combine two queries, one based upon the other, into one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two queries, one based partly on the other. Is there a way of combining them into a single query?

```
SELECT tblIssues.*, tblIssues.NewsletterLookup
FROM tblIssues
WHERE (((tblIssues.NewsletterLookup)=5));

SELECT tblArea.ID, tblArea.AreaName
FROM tblArea LEFT JOIN Query2 ON tblArea.ID = Query2.[AreaLookup]
WHERE (((tblArea.Dormant)=False) AND ((Query2.tblIssues.NewsletterLookup) Is Null));
```

Comment: Doesn't Access complain about that second example query because of `Query2.tblIssues.NewsletterLookup`?

Comment: @HansUp, I believe, it was just an example OP was trying to point his requirement. where `Query2` is nothing but the 1st query

Comment: Access doesn't complain. The two queries give me excatly what I want - I would like to do it all in just one query on its own. I don't understand how I get the contents of the first query where Query2 is in the second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in a single query without *Query2*, you can use the equivalent SQL from *Query2* as a subquery in your second example:

```sql
SELECT a.ID, a.AreaName
FROM
    tblArea AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT i.*
            FROM tblIssues AS i
            WHERE i.NewsletterLookup=5
        ) AS sub
    ON a.ID = sub.[AreaLookup]
WHERE
        a.Dormant=False
    AND sub.NewsletterLookup Is Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You ment to perform a `JOIN` like

```
SELECT ti.*, tblArea.ID, tblArea.AreaName
FROM tblArea ta
LEFT JOIN tblIssues ti ON ta.ID = ti.[AreaLookup]
WHERE (ti.NewsletterLookup=5 OR ti.NewsletterLookup Is Null)
AND ta.Dormant=False;
```

Comment: This: ti.NewsletterLookup=5 gives an error message 'JOIN expression not supported.'

Comment: @GreatCrosby, Ahh!! MS Access. my bad missed that. See edit in answer if that helps.